# Create embedded column xml with a sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with below records in it.

```
+------------+---------+
|    State   |Strength |
+------------+---------+
| AR         | 10000   |
| AK         | 20000   |
+------------+---------+
```

I want to general xml in the below format

```
<Fields><AR>10000</AR><AK>20000</AK></Fields>
```

What I've tried so far.

```
SELECT '<'+State+'>' + Strength+'</'+State+'>'
FROM tbl
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('Fields')
```

Result I get -  `<Fields>&lt;AR&gt;10000&lt;/AR&gt;&lt;AK&gt;20000&lt;/AK&gt;</Fields>`

Comment: It may help you https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-the-for-xml-clause-to-return-query-results-as-xml/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `type` for xml path and `value` method

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE (State varchar(20), Strength int)
INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES ('AR', 10000), ('AK', 20000) ,('MP', 30000)

SELECT (SELECT  CONCAT('<',sd.State,'>', sd.Strength, '</',sd.State, '>')
FROM @SampleData sd
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Reference link: [Type for xml sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/type-directive-in-for-xml-queries)

Or simple query like that

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE (State varchar(20), Strength int)
INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES ('AR', 10000), ('AK', 20000) ,('MP', 30000)

DECLARE @xml nvarchar(max) = N'<Fields>'
SELECT @xml += CONCAT('<',sd.State,'>', sd.Strength, '</',sd.State, '>')
FROM @SampleData sd

SET @xml  += N'</ Fields>'

SELECT @xml
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'm using SQL Server 2008 and don't have a CONCAT function. However, I was able to manually append them and get it working. `SELECT @xml += '<' + sd,State + and so on`

Answer (score 1):

TriV's would be my first choice  (already +1)

But, another option (just for fun) is via a PIVOT ... dynamic or not

**Dynamic**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([State]) From tbl  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select @SQL = '
Select *
 From  (
        Select *
         From  (
                 Select Col=[State]
                       ,Val=[Strength] 
                  From tbl
               ) A
         Pivot (max([Val]) For [Col] in ('+@SQL+') )p
        ) A
for XML Path(''''),Root(''Fields'')
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Static**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select *
         From  (
                 Select Col=[State]
                       ,Val=[Strength] 
                  From tbl
               ) A
         Pivot (max([Val]) For [Col] in ([AK],[AR]) )p
        ) A
for XML Path(''),Root('Fields')
```

**Both Return**

```
<Fields>
  <AK>20000</AK>
  <AR>10000</AR>
</Fields>
```